# vim cursor style persists on terminal after quitting vim

Tags: linux, vim

I wanted vim to have a block cursor in normal mode and vertical cursor in insert mode, so I added the following code to .vimrc:

```
let &t_SI = "\e[6 q"
let &t_EI = "\e[2 q"

" reset the cursor on start (for older versions of vim, usually not required)
augroup myCmds
au!
autocmd VimEnter * silent !echo -ne "\e[2 q"
augroup END
```

In my terminal I want (and have) the vertical line style cusor.
However, now when I enter and exist vim, on the terminal from which I invoked vim I am left with the block cursor

[image: gif animation so you see what's going on]

Comment: What is your OS? Your vim is pure vim or neovim? What is your terminal? Is it bash?

Comment: Well, your snippet obviously handles entering Vim but not leaving it.

Comment: Philippe's answer solved it for me, but I will explain myself further.
@yves pure vim, this happened to me both on bash and on tcsh, both in windows terminal running windows subsystem for linux with ubuntu, and with MATE terminal running linux.

Comment: @romainl I though it's a vim cfg file. I didn't realize things that I do there can persist outside of it.

Comment: @NimrodWeinberg, not everything can but what that trick does is that it emits a special sequence that puts the terminal in a special mode. What you change with it is the terminal, not Vim. Since you only want that change when you are in Vim, then you must set it up when you enter Vim and revert it when you leave it.

Comment: IMHO, don't waste of time on this issue because you are working with non-standard environment(windows terminal + subsystem etc). If Philippe's answer helps, do what he said. This kind of compatibility issue is acceptable and don't waste time on it.

Comment: @Yves
Sorry if I was unclear. I meant to say it happened to me in 2 completely separate environments. 1 was WSL, but the 2nd one was straight up linux. both envs run on different OSs and different terminals. the environments are so different from each other that I figured that the issue must be global and that's why I didn't provide particular details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can tell `vim` to restore vertical cursor on exit :

```
autocmd VimLeave * silent !echo -ne "\e[6 q"
```

*(star) : for all types of files

silent : To avoid the message box that pops up to report the result

!echo -ne : Run shell command [echo -ne ...]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution!
2 things though - 1. it is causing me very slow shutdown of vim, as well as my "autocmd VimEnter * silent !echo -ne "\e[2 q" " which is causing very slow start up. Do you know why?
2. can you elaborate a bit on "*", "silent", "-ne"? thanks

Comment: I just tested on Ubuntu&Cygwin/Windows Terminal, the two commands don't slow down the startup or shutdown of vim.